# Auto refreshing div in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

While implementing auto refreshing div in jQuery that fetches updates on posts periodically as can be seen on Twitter, Facebook etc.

I had to think about making the refresh as efficient as possible. I decided to send a request to the server every 30 seconds - 1 minute. And, the request will be sent only if the browser window is active.

```
var postUpdateIntervalID;
var interval = 30000;

$(window).load(function(){
    if (!postUpdateIntervalID) {
        postUpdateIntervalID = setInterval(function() {
            updatePostsList();
        }, interval);
    }
});

$(window).focus(function(){
    if (!postUpdateIntervalID) {
        updatePostsList();
        postUpdateIntervalID = setInterval(function() {
            updatePostsList();
        }, interval);
    }
});

$(window).blur(function() {
    clearInterval(postUpdateIntervalID);
    postUpdateIntervalID = 0;
});

function updatePostsList() {
    // Sends a request to the server to fetch new posts.
}
```

1. On load, set interval of 30 seconds to call `updatePostsList`.
2. On focus, call `updatePostsList` immediately. Then, set interval as above.
3. On blur, reset the interval.

Comment: This seems like a sensible model, since you can't setup a proper Observer pattern. You could send out an AJAX request with no timeout, and have the server not respond until it needs too. That would be able the closest to an Observer pattern as you could get I would think.

Comment: Is this for a simple web-page/site, or a more complex webapp integration?

Comment: For a complex webapp integration. Is that question to estimate the power of the webserver and the database server?

Comment: Focus/Blur isn't a solid bet. I'm willing to bet at least one user will use two monitors and leave your "feed" up on one screen, while using the other and wonder why it isn't working.

Comment: In firefox and IE the focus event will fire after the window has loaded so your code might be redundant.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408699/using-jquery-to-bind-focus-and-blur-functions-for-window-doesnt-work-in

Also, why are you calling the updatePostsList() directly in the focus handler but not in the load handler?

Comment: That's a very good point Robert. I call the updatePostsList directly as soon as the browser gets focus. SO that as soon as the user returns, an update happens. Its not a perfect solution but I consider it a work around. Do u have any suggestions?

Comment: Well, I clear the interval on blur. So when the user gets back, focus is fired. I handle the focus by calling updatePostsList. So that the user sees the updated list as soon as he gets back to the website. After that the normal interval thingy continues. That's why the function is called directly on focus but not on load. Plus, initially the data is displayed using the server-side language only. So, no need to call updatePostsList immediately.

Comment: DeviantSeev -> Actually, the focus event is fired on window load on chrome as well. But my focus event handler does its thing only if the variable "postUpdateIntervalID" is not set. Load event handler sets it. So repetition does not occur. On blur, the variable is resetted. So, when the user comes back and focus event is fired, it does its thang!! ;)

Answer (score 2):

If this is for a complex web application, I would recommend using some sort of MVC framework. Personally I prefer backbone.js. Here are some great resources that should help you develop a maintainable app, as well help with updating and refreshing views.

MVC explanation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649643.aspx

Backbone.js: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/

Connection between the two: http://css.dzone.com/articles/backbonejs-mvc-javascript

As a more direct answer to your question, I believe the code you have looks fine. But if you have multiples modules in your application, running view refresh functions on timers is not a good idea.